# Linked tooltip on heatmap and sparkline

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I created a heatmap and sparklines next to the heatmap.

[**HERE**](http://plnkr.co/edit/SOgAZKfmNlh7TtfwN1Cd) **the Plunker**

Now I would like that when the user hovers over a cell of the heatmap, a red dot is displayed on the corresponding sparkline.
On the other hand, when the user hovers over the sparkline, the corresponding cell in the heatmap is highlighted.

I hope it's clearer with some drawings:

[image]

I thought I could change the code at this point:

```
var cells = svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .append('rect')
    //...
    .on('mouseover', tip.show) // <- HERE
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

I should keep track of the rectangle on which the mouse is located and somehow pass this data to the piece of code that controls the sparkline.
But I don't really know how to do it and I have not found similar examples.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HERE MY PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/zYxbZy?p=info)
add this liblary:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

To solve your problem, you need understand the concept,

1. The D3 can holding data when you put on it
2. The D3 can select base on class and id
3. The DOM element can hold attribute (Ex: attr-id)
4. Scale linear can be invers, that mean if you have domain you can have range and if you have range you can have domain
5. Element that draw with D3 is updatable & deletable
6. understand the liblary you use (d3-tip)

**What i Change**

1. i add class and id to element i want to select
2. if i want to use data, i save data to data-attribute
3. i make function to track my mouse on Line-chart, and invers it to get value
4. i draw object tip i want to use

> read the code if you want to understand ask me which line you dont understand, if you need explanation